# command not found: ganache-cli

Tags: node.js, npm, ganache

I have installed and reinstalled npm to try to run ganache and it has not been successful..really need help here!

---

(base) user bin % npm install -g ganache-cli

changed 6 packages, and audited 102 packages in 4s

2 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

8 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 1 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
(base) user bin % ganache-cli
zsh: command not found: ganache-cli

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the global modules installation directory is not in your path. As a quick workaround, you can run it like this:

```
`npm root -g`/ganache-cli/cli.js
```

A better idea (aside from fixing your PATH!) would be to install it as a dev dependency in the project that needs it (so `npm install -D` instead of `npm install -g`) and then run it with `npx` (so `npx ganache-cli` rather than `ganache-cli`).

Answer (score 5):

For Win10:
update PATH env variable adding

```
C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin
```

FYI: In that dir there are 2 files:

```
ganache-cli
ganache-cli.cmd
```

Answer (score 5):

if you are on linux(my case ubuntu) and you encoutered this issue. you should try

```
    $sudo npm install -g ganache
```

#### OR

```
    $sudo yarn global add ganache
```

This is probably because you used sudo privileges to install npm and yarn in first place.
happy hacking :)